# Lambda function causing TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, typeerror

I just started learning Python. I'm using an API to build an IDFs model,however I'm facing some errors with the lambda functions which I cannot resolve.
This the class that generates the IDF:

```
class Idfs(DocumentFrequencies, Model):

    def build(self, corpus):
        log.info('Counting documents in corpus...')
        N = float(corpus.count())
        dfs = super(Idfs, self).build(corpus)

        log.info('Building idf model: N=%i', N)
        return dfs\
           .map(lambda (term, (df,rank)): (term, df))\  
           .mapValues(lambda df: math.log(N/df))

    @staticmethod
    def format_item((term, idf)):
        return {
        '_id': term,
        'idf': idf,
        }
```

And the this is the class that count the DF:

```
class DocumentFrequencies(ModelBuilder):

    def __init__(self, lowercase=False, max_ngram=1, min_df=2):
        self.lowercase = lowercase
        self.max_ngram = max_ngram
        self.min_df = min_df

    def build(self, docs):
        m = docs.map(lambda d: d['text'])
        if self.lowercase:
            m = m.map(lambda text: text.lower())

        return m\
            .flatMap(lambda text: set(ngrams(text, self.max_ngram)))\
            .map(lambda t: (t, 1))\
            .reduceByKey(add)\
            .filter(lambda (k,v): v > self.min_df)
```

The error appears in this line `.map(lambda (term, (df, rank)): (term, df))\` and this is the error message :

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

This is what I get when I call `DocumentFrequencies.collect()`:

```
Out[5]:                                                                         
[(u'fawn', 3),
 (u'1,800', 31),
 (u'clotted', 3),
 (u'comically', 11),
 (u'Adjusting', 3),
 (u'O(log', 6),
 (u'unnecessarily', 15),
 (u'evangelical', 53),
 (u'naturopathic', 3),
 (u'grenadiers', 4),
 (u'stipulate', 4),
 (u'Vikrant', 3),
 (u'fractal', 18),
```

I dont know which argument exactly is causing the error. I'm using python 2.7, 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR with 2 cores. These are the pyspark configs:

```
conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAll([('spark.executor.memory', '8g'),('spark.driver.memory','8g'),('spark.network.timeout','100000000s'),('spark.executor.heartbeatInterval','10000000s'),('spark.driver.maxResultSize','8g'),('spark.driver.cores','2')])
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I am not familiar with the Idfs and Dfs but looks like `dfs` variable is not an iterable. For example, lists and strings are iterables through which you can iterate. Please log `dfs` once and see what you are getting.

Comment: As mentioned in the error, you are passing int value which is not iterable. check for input.

Comment: @nightgaunt I tried logging it and this what I got `12:03:54,896|INFO|text|PythonRDD[32] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:48  ` not very useful. Any idea how to print the actual output?

Comment: If the `dfs` is RDD, then map should have worked. You can try `dfs.collect()` and log. Can you also add the complete trace? Now I get a feeling it might not be the place where error is happening

Comment: @nightgaunt GREAT, on it. I think I should log IDF since it call DF and the error is caused in IDF.

Comment: @nightgaunt This is what I get when I call the `dfs.collect()` :

Comment: @nightgaunt Just edited the questions to show all the info you asked :) Thank you

Comment: If the `dfs` has a python tuple, then `lambda (term, (df, rank):` doesn't make sense. It should be just `lambda (term, df:`

Comment: @nightgaunt but if i edit the api method to `.map(lambda (term, df): (term,df))` wouldn't that make the line useless? I also dont get where the `rank` values should be coming from? as shown `dfs` are only producing `term` and `df`.

Comment: @nightgaunt THANK YOU I removed `rank` and idfs are counted correctly now. However when I try to store it still seems empty! is it the pyspark? I edited the question again to reflect the changes.

Comment: As you mentioned, `.map(lambda (term, df): (term,df))` is redundant. You can remove it if you want to. Not sure how `mmap` works.

Comment: @nightgaunt could you add you suggestion of removing "rank" as an answer so I can up vote or select it as an answer. Thank you for your help

Comment: @nightgaunt could you please take a look at this too, thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50390255/too-many-values-to-unpack-in-lambda-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on `DocumentFrequencies.collect()` output,

```
map(lambda (term, (df,rank)): (term, df))
```

Shouldn't exist. Basically it is trying to convert the given tuple `(u'fawn', 3)` into two parts. `u'fawn'` is mapped to `term` and `3` is mapped to `(df,rank)`. Since the integer 3 cannot be converted to a tuple (which is iterable), the error message

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Removing this line will not change anything in the dfs.

Comment: Could you please take a look at this question also :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50390255/lambda-function-causing-too-many-values-to-unpack