# Too many values to unpack in lambda function

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, lambda, pyspark

I just started learning Python. I'm using an API to build a TFIDFs model, however I'm facing some errors with the lambda functions which I cannot resolve. This is part of the class that generates the TFIDFs:

```
class tfidf(ModelBuilder, Model):

    def __init__(self, max_ngram=1, normalize = True):
        self.max_ngram = max_ngram
        self.normalize = normalize

    def build(self, mentions, idfs):
        m = mentions\
            .map(lambda (target, (span, text)): (target, text))\  """error is triggered here  """
            .mapValues(lambda v: ngrams(v, self.max_ngram))\
            .flatMap(lambda (target, tokens): (((target, t), 1) for t in tokens))\
            .reduceByKey(add)\
            .map(lambda ((target, token), count): (token, (target, count)))\
            .leftOuterJoin(idfs)\
```

And here is a sample output of the `mentions` class (which is the input causing the error in `tdfidf` class):

```
Out[24]:                                                                        
[{'_id': u'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Cowper',
  'source': 'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beagle',
  'span': (165, 179),
  'text': u'References to the dog appear before the 19th century in works by such writers as William Shakespeare, John Webster, John Dryden, Thomas Tickell, Henry Fielding, and William Cowper, as well as in Alexander Pope\'s translation of Homer\'s "Iliad".'},
 {'_id': u"en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-Run's_Park_Me_In_First",
  'source': 'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beagle',
  'span': (32, 62),
  'text': u" On 12 February 2008, a Beagle, K-Run's Park Me In First (Uno), won the Best In Show category at the Westminster Kennel Club show for the first time in the competition's history."},
```

The error message is:

```
 .map(lambda (target, (span, text)): (target, text))\
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I tried:  `.map(lambda ( src, target, span, text) : (target, text))\` since I only need the target and text which causes the same error in `mentions\`.

A simple and a compilable example:

```
import math
import numpy


Data = [{'_id': '333981',

  'source': 'Apple',

  'span': (100, 119),

  'text': ' It is native to the northern Pacific.'}, {'_id': '27262',

  'source': 'Apple',

  'span': (4, 20),

  'text': ' Apples are yummy.'}]



m = map(lambda (ID, (span, text)) : (ID, text) , Data)

print(list(m))
```

I'm using python 2.7. Any help or guidance will be much appreciated.

Many thanks,

Comment: @JHBonarius I think it's different, could a `.iteritems()` be used in lambda? if yes can you give a hint. thanks

Comment: I was to quick to judge. But I cannot reproduce your error. Could you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Not familiar with Spark, but it seems like the `mentions` items are dicts or dict-like objects with four items. How exactly do you expect those to unpack to `(target, (span, text))`?

Comment: Could you please tell us which API you are using? An internet search threw up several.

Comment: @PaulaThomas Sure, here is the link https://github.com/wikilinks/sift/blob/master/sift/models/text.py

Comment: @JHBonarius Unfortunately, I cant. I dont have the enough knowledge to reproduce the error in a simpler scenario :(

Comment: Your `mentions` is what you described in `Out[24]` ?

Comment: @eqperes yes those are the inputs of the line causing the error.

Comment: And what do you expect `target` to be ?

Comment: @eqperes it's the ` _id': u'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Cowper `

Comment: Then try to replace the line that raises the error by `.map(lambda mention: (mention["_id"], mention["text"]))`

Comment: @eqperes did that and I got the error now pointing at ` m = mentions\
ValueError: too many values to unpack`. i added the full trace in the question

Comment: @JHBonarius I added a simple and readable example that produces the  same error. Thank you for your help

Comment: Do you want to create a new list of dictionaries containing only source and text? `m = [{'source': item.get('source'), 'text': item.get('text')} for item in Data]`? Or as map `m = map(lambda item: {'source': item.get('source'), 'text': item.get('text')}, Data)`...

Comment: @JHBonarius I'll test this suggestion, thank you

Comment: @JHBonarius do we have to specify the key if we are running on pyspark? I dont think the API author missed this.

Comment: I don't know pyspark. But you need insight on the layout of your dictionary. `(target, (span, text))` doesn't match the layout, hence the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a new array of dictionaries containing only the fields `source` and `text`, you could use

```
m = map(lambda item: {field: item.get(field) for field in ['source', 'text']}, Data)
```

If you want to create an array of tuples of the contents for the keys `source` and `text`:

```
m = map(lambda item: (item.get('source'), item.get('text')), Data)
```

Comment: I tried it this is what appears now `/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1979, in <lambda>
    map_values_fn = lambda kv: (kv[0], f(kv[1]))
KeyError: 0`. Thank you for your help the solution might be different.

Comment: @user3446905: that's regarding the next line `.mapValues(lambda v: ngrams(v, self.max_ngram))`. The code you are showing doesn't seem to be compatible with your dictionary layout.

Comment: @user3446905 could it be that you need only a tuple of the key contents? E.g. `.map(lambda item: (item.get('source'), item.get('text'))`

Comment: could the new error mean that this line `.map(lambda (target, (span, text)): (target, text))\`  should stay the same? meaning that  `span` and `text` should come as a tuple?

Comment: doesnt this  `item.get('source') ` retrieve the actual data and not the keys?

Comment: `ngrams() ` in the second line should receive text

Comment: @user3446905 yes it gets the data. Then: the line means the tuple-of-tuple `(target, (span, text))` is converted to tuple `(target, text)`.

Comment: tried your last suggestion caused the same next line error. The next line expects two tuples, and performs the ngrams function on kv[1]. While the third line takes the target (from line 1) and the resulted tokens (from line 2).

Comment: OK. The problem is that I'm not familiar with PySpark. I just tried to get it to run in my Python IDE, but that doesn't seem so evident. I just know how to fix stuff in basic Python. Maybe you can use my suggestions for an eventual solution. Good luck. P.s. you could think about converting your dictionaries to tuples.